# How to compare strings between each other in loop in NightWatch

Tags: javascript, xpath, automation, nightwatch.js

I'm working with NightWatch JS and I have a question, how can I compare strings and check for unique in the loop in NightwatchJS?

```
My code module.exports = {

    test: function(client) {
        
        var text1;

        client
            .maximizeWindow()
            .url('https://gitlab.com/')
            .waitForElementVisible('svg.nav-logo', 10 * 1000)
            .click('#CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonAccept')
            .useXpath()
            .moveToElement('(//h2[contains(text(),"The latest from our blog")]//following-sibling::div/a/div/h4)',1,1)
            .waitForElementVisible('(//h2[contains(text(),"The latest from our blog")]//following-sibling::div/a/div/h4)', 10 * 1000)
            .elements('xpath','(//h2[contains(text(),"The latest from our blog")]//following-sibling::div/a/div/h4)', 
            function(elements)
            {
               elements.value.forEach(function(elementsObj)
               {
                    client.elementIdText(elementsObj.ELEMENT,function(result){
                        text1 = result.value;
                        console.log(text1);
                    })
               }) 
            })
            .pause(10*1000);
    }
};
```

In the console, I received the expected result (3 strings)
There is a question, how now I can check, how to compare that each string is unique in the loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an **map** to check whether the strings are unique or not. If an similar string is already present in the map, then that string will never be added again. So in your case if all the three texts are unique, then the size of the map should be 3, which you can assert at the end of your test.

```
let uniqueStrings = new Map()
My code module.exports = {
    test: function(client) {
        var text1;
        client.maximizeWindow()
          .url('https://gitlab.com/')
          .waitForElementVisible('svg.nav-logo', 10 * 1000)
          .click('#CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonAccept')
          .useXpath()
          .moveToElement('(//h2[contains(text(),"The latest from our blog")]//following-sibling::div/a/div/h4)', 1, 1)
          .waitForElementVisible('(//h2[contains(text(),"The latest from our blog")]//following-sibling::div/a/div/h4)', 10 * 1000)
          .elements('xpath', '(//h2[contains(text(),"The latest from our blog")]//following-sibling::div/a/div/h4)', function(elements) {
            elements.value.forEach(function(elementsObj) {
                client.elementIdText(elementsObj.ELEMENT, function(result) {
                    text1 = result.value;
                    console.log(text1);
                    uniqueStrings.set(text1.trim())
                })
            })
            client.assert.equal(uniqueStrings.size, 3)
        }).pause(10 * 1000);
    }
};
```

Comment: Something is not working correctly. Received error in console × Failed [equal]: (0 == 3) - expected "3" but got: "0"

Comment: I have updated my answer. can you try once?

Comment: can you do a `console.log(uniqueStrings.size)` instead of `client.assert.equal(uniqueStrings.size, 3)` and check what is printed ?

Comment: After execution printed ''0''', but 0 is printed before elements are checked

Comment: 0
How to integrate GitLab.com with Jira Cloud
Map(1) { 0 => 'How to integrate GitLab.com with Jira Cloud' }
We're open sourcing Protocol Fuzzer Community Edition!
Map(2) {
  0 => 'How to integrate GitLab.com with Jira Cloud',
  1 => "We're open sourcing Protocol Fuzzer Community Edition!"
}
How you contribute to GitLab's open DevOps platform
Map(3) {
  0 => 'How to integrate GitLab.com with Jira Cloud',
  1 => "We're open sourcing Protocol Fuzzer Community Edition!",
  2 => "How you contribute to GitLab's open DevOps platform"

Comment: Ok then that means that the strings are getting stored in the map. You just need to move the assert statement one step ahead then as the assert is executed before the map has any values in it.

Comment: Can you please update the code? I'm not sure that I understand you correctly